# "Callback was already called" error with mocha + chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

While writing some basic mocha tests for a node app I keep encountering this weird bug. Seemingly randomly the following set of tests fail and throw a "Callback was already called" error.

```js
describe('#timeChecks()', () => {
    it('should produce no results. times dont overlap. using minute form', (done) => {
        const rider1 = new Rider(1, 10, new Date('2011-12-01 00:00:00'), new Time(803), new Time(1320), [sj], cp);
        const driver1 = new Driver(1, 11, new Date('2011-12-01 00:00:00'), new Time(0), new Time(758), [], sf, cp, 1200, 20, 3);

        map_riders_to_drivers([rider1], [driver1], (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            expect(res).to.have.length(0);

            done();
        });
    });

    it('should produce 1 results. times overlap. using minute form', (done) => {
        const rider1 = new Rider(1, 10, new Date('2011-12-01 00:00:00'), new Time(703), new Time(920), [sj], cp);
        const driver1 = new Driver(1, 11, new Date('2011-12-01 00:00:00'), new Time(510), new Time(858), [], sf, cp, 2600, 20, 3);

        map_riders_to_drivers([rider1], [driver1], (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            expect(res).to.have.length(1);

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Running the following two tests occasionally causes an error to occur:

Failed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICHnS.png

Success: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i4T7.png

I have already tried removing chai and simply using if statements. I assume that a race condition is occurring causing the bug to appear random. err in both cases is null and res appears to return expected values when logging the values. What could possible be going on? I have many other test cases that work fine together but the second test here appears to cause problems. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the error is thrown in the `async` module, so it happens somewhere in your classes.

Comment: Thank you that was it. I'm kicking myself for not seeing that.

Comment: @LukasFroehlich could you provide an answer to how you solved it? I'm facing the same issue. It's a combination of async and mocha, and probably something small, but I'm breaking my head over it.